# Подcкажите редакторы SVG куда можно загрузит svg и отобразятся точки координат за которые можно таскать и менять координаты?

Tags: html, svg

Подскажите редакторы SVG куда можно загрузит svg и отобразятся точки координат за которые можно таскать и менять координаты?
или можно есть приложение для хрома?
Что подобное этому `codepen.io/wokster/pen/qyrywL`

Comment: inkscape illustrator corel draw

Comment: А простые онлаин,только для этой задачи,чтоб не скаичивать и не устанавливать?

Comment: это геморой - проще inkscape ни чего нету - я большенство примеров делаю в inkscape щас купил и осваиваю illustrator но давно купил corel редко им пользуюсь так как inkscape всё может но есть минусы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для рисования простых фигур есть и такие редакторы:

[editor.method](https://editor.method.ac/)

[svg-edit.github.io](https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/latest/editor/svg-editor.html)

### Генераторы криволинейных путей

- [SVG GENERATOR PATH](https://smooth.ie/blogs/news/svg-wavey-transitions-between-sections)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень удобная вещь.

Перемещаете узловые точки, двигаете рычаги, а внизу пишется код патча.

Может быть использован для написания кода для фигурной шапки сайта, для анимашек волн и т.д и т.п

*Полученный код из генераторов, в период освоения SVG, лучше добавлять инлайн способом, то есть непосредственным копированием в `HTML`*

- [Path Length Calculator](https://codepen.io/gabriellewee/pen/EZPYmw)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Копируете формулу `path` и получаете его максимальную длину.

Вычисление длины `path` необходима для написания кода анимации рисования линий, посредством изменения атрибута `stroke-dasharray`

- [SVG Path Builder](https://codepen.io/anthonydugois/pen/mewdyZ)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляете, удаляете, перемещаете узловые точки для получения нужной формы кривой. В нижнем правом углу автоматом пишется код `path`

### Генераторы clipPath

- https://codepen.io/jh3y/pen/XqVQqa
- http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Comment: Есть куда загрузить мой SVG и редактировать его

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти сейчас добавлю парочку редакторов

Comment: <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" transform="matrix(1.6 0 0 1.6 0 0)" d="M 83.568 0 C 82.231 19.474 57.318 29.714 43.662 43.662 C 29.734 57.887 19.696 82.397 0 85.293 C -20.715 88.338 -43.216 72.696 -56.577 56.576 C -68.985 41.606 -70.798 19.315 -73.032 0 C -75.666 -22.772 -84.256 -51.937 -69.37 -69.37 C -54.17 -87.169 -22.937 -88.822 -0.001 -84.157 C 19.538 -80.183 35.434 -63.633 49.476 -49.477 C 63.441 -35.401 84.927 -19.782 83.568 0 Z " fill="rgb(13,216,216)"/>

Comment: @ЭнрикоТакатти Сохраняете свой код или чужой в файл *.svg открываете в редакторе, которые я добавил в самом верху ответа